# Xamarin android archive failed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk, archive

I want to archive my android project in xamarin to get apk file but I get this error:

```
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2550,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

this is my project properties:
[image]

I really have no idea what is the problem.
Any help?

Comment: It seems there is conflict between the compile version and the target Android version. Please set them to the same version and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

Clean and build your project. Restart visual studio. Then again archive. this issue comes due to conflicts sometimes.

Comment: Out of all the answers I've found for this issue, this is literally the only one that has worked for me, thanks.